# How do I use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension for Chrome. I want to show an alert() with the page URL whenever the user moves from one tab to another, or when the user enters a new URL in a tab.

This is not working:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab) {
    alert(changeInfo.url);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(object activeInfo) {
    // also please post how to fetch tab url using activeInfo.tabid
});
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Remove `integer`, `object` and `Tab` in the functions signature. Also change `.onUpdated` to `.onActivated`

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   alert(changeInfo.url);
}); 

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  // how to fetch tab url using activeInfo.tabid
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
     console.log(tab.url);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this code not work anymore? I'm using this as a popup.js included in my popup.html. Won't work in my background or content-script either.

Comment: This is probably too late for Rohit, but make sure you have `"tabs"` in the `permissions` array in the extension manifest.  Otherwise, you won't get the tab URL or title.

Answer (score 2):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab)=>{
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    },(tabs)=>{
        if(changeInfo.url && tabId === tabs[0].id) {
            console.log("Only Current TAB");
        };
    })})
```

> This will give if only the current tab is updated.